# "Unknown column 'postcode' in 'where clause'"

Tags: mysql

> MySQL 8.0.12 Windows 64-bit

I am trying to set up an SQL query to search my database by any matching postcodes and I am currently running into a problem. I am able to SELECT using the column name "postcode" but when I enter it into the WHERE clause as such "postcode = 4000" MySQL tells me about the column being unknown.

As I was trying to search up solutions to this problem (as this error message is very common) I came across three primary types of typical solutions. Using the backtick or not using the backtick depending on if there are spaces in your column name etc., not relying purely on alias names due to the execution order of the query and making sure that other punctuation such as quotation marks don't confuse the query executor. I have tried with and without the backticks, and I am not relying on any aliases currently but I have experimented with using aliases in different orders to see if it will work and I have removed any other typically suspect punctuation marks but nothing is working thus far.

The query used for creating the table is as such...

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodes` (
  `?postcode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locality` text,
  `State` text,
  `long` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dc` text,
  `type` text,
  `status` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

My query that I wish to run is as such...

```sql
SELECT postcode FROM au_locations.postcodes WHERE postcode = 4000;
```

...and I have tried over adaptations of this query...

```sql
SELECT `postcode` FROM `au_locations`.`postcodes` WHERE `postcode` = 4000;
SELECT postcode FROM au_locations.postcodes WHERE au_locations.postcode = 4000;
```

...and most confusingly to me this query *was* working completely fine on its own, but the next day I ran it, it was not working anymore...

```sql
SELECT postcode FROM au_locations.postcodes;
```

The error I have come across is defined as such...

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'postcode' in 'where clause'

With this query working I hope to simply output a single column single row table with the value "4000" and the heading "postcode". Is there any important identifiers or other code that I am missing out on currently?

NOTE: There appears to be no triggers or other parameters active on the database, and any attempt to reconstruct the table in another database with the CREATE TABLE definition provided above produces identical results. The table was initially produced from a CSV file and from all appearances it seems that the CSV file was properly implemented, it is only when I query WHERE postcode that any error appears (all other columns work fine).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195414/discussion-on-question-by-james-unknown-column-postcode-in-where-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to assistance provided by all commenters and Progman (discussion which can be viewed at this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195414/discussion-on-question-by-james-unknown-column-postcode-in-where-clause)) the question has been solved.

By running SHOW CREATE TABLE in the MySQL client on Windows I was able to discover an additional character that was likely not encoded properly in the field name "postcode" and was therefore confusing MySQL when I was running queries relating to the field "postcode". It is possible this was an error relating to line feed characters and other characters that slightly differ in operation between OS's but I have no particular evidence to back that theory as of the moment (will add to the comments if I do find the reason).

To find the MySQL client on Windows you can either search "mysql" in your Windows search bar, or you can open Command Prompt and navigate to where your MySQL folder is located (most likely C:\Program Files\MySQL) and depending on what version of MySQL you have, you will need to run the mysql command in a differing folder. Further [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html) on running the mysql command to open the client can be found here.

After discovering the reason for this error, I retyped out the headings for the columns of the CSV file in NotePad++ to ensure that there were no additional lurking characters and re-imported my CSV file into MySQL which now worked.